# How to auto reset input value (formGroup) in angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using the angular form to make a search bar in the "search page" ("/search"). I notice if I have searched something, e.g "testing word". Then, I go to home page ("/") and
go back to the search page, the input of searching bar, "testing word" remains.

I thought I use `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy`, but it seems not work (ngOnDestroy is called based on console log "haha"). I know if using button click event to reset the `searchTerm` will work. However, I would like to have the values reset automatically when we leave the search page. How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
    <input matInput type="type" autocomplete="off" formControlName="search">
    <mat-placeholder>Search</mat-placeholder>
  </mat-form-field>
  <a mat-icon-button aria-label="Search" (click)="emitState()">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
  </a>
</form>

---------------

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  private searchSub!: Subscription;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    super();
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      search: ['', []],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const searchTerms = this.values[0].value as string;
    this.searchForm.get('search')?.setValue(searchTerms);

    this.searchSub = this.searchForm.controls.search.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(400), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(
        (term) => {
          this.values[0].value = term;
          this.emitState();
        },
        (err) => console.log(err)
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.searchSub.unsubscribe();
    console.log("haha")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling this.searchSub.unsubscribe will only unsubscribe to the value changes that you are listing to. I think you should be able to add this.searchForm.reset() to your ngOnDestroy to clear the form.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.searchSub.unsubscribe();
  this.searchForm.reset()
  console.log("haha")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comments. Adding reset() alone without clicking event will not work

Comment: No worries. Do you want to click a button and have the input clear or are you looking to clear the text when the component is destroyed? The code from my answer will clear the text without clicking a button. It will clear the input when the component is destroyed

Comment: I would like to have it cleared when the component is destroyed. The issue is when I just put `this.searchForm.reset()` in the `ngOnDestroy`, the input text remains, which I still don't know why.

Comment: I just checked the `searchForm` values. It did reset `value: {search: null}` after component destroys, but the UI still has the text remaining on the searchbar. I think putting`reset()` in ngOnDestroy() works, but there is something we missed to clear text in the UI part.

Comment: I see, I do see in your ngOnInit you are setting the searchForm based on "this.values[0].value as string". I'm not seeing where this.values is being set in your code snippet. Do you know where that is getting set or passed in?